# Getting complex cross sale details in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have an issue where i need to find out the details of the revenue that got from a cross sale product.
For example, I want to know which all are the category combinations a customer buy with a selected category.Also the amount spend by that customer on other categories other than the selected category.

Below is a sample Query which will give me the combinations and the revenue, Using a filter clause i can get the revenue of the category with and without the selected category if the combination count is 2 category, But when there more than 2 category in combinations i need to get the info how much each category cost, How can i get it?

Database : PostgreSQL Version 11

```
WITH filter_2 as
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
                 o.order_number
               , o.client_email
               , COALESCE(category,'') AS category_name
               , SUM(revenue) as revenue
          FROM  
                     orders o
          INNER JOIN distinct_orders dos on dos.client_email=o.client_email
          LEFT JOIN items i ON i.order_id = o.order_id
          LEFT JOIN products p ON p.product_id = i.product_id 
      WHERE  o.state ='Done'
      GROUP BY o.order_number
    , o.client_email, COALESCE(category,'')
    )
    
    ,result_set_1 as
    (
        SELECT 
         f.order_number
        ,f.client_email
        ,string_agg(DISTINCT COALESCE(category,''), ' , ' ORDER BY COALESCE(category,'')) as cat_level_3_name
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT category) as prod_count
       
      ,SUM(revenue) revenue
        FROM filter_2 f
    GROUP BY f.order_number,f.client_email
    )
    SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT order_number) as order_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT client_email) as customer_count
    ,category
    ,SUM(revenue) as revenue
    FROM result_set_1 r
    WHERE category IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY category
    ORDER BY order_count DESC
```

Sample Input

```
Order_number   client_email     category  Revenue
"819214"    "olx@gmail.com"     "A Tea" 290.00
"819214"    "olx@gamil.com"     "B Tea" 10.00
"608759"    "lixxx@gmail.com"   "A Tea" 15.00
"608759"    "lixxx@yahoo.com"   "B Tea" 20.00
"608759"    "lixxx@gmail.com"   "C Tea" 400.00
"237070"    "news@gmail.com"    "A Tea" 60.0
"237070"    "news@gmail.com"    "B Tea" 10.0
"508759"    "chink@gmail.com"   "A Tea" 15.00
"508759"    "chink@gmail.com"   "B Tea" 25.00
"508759"    "chink@gmail.com"   "C Tea" 45.00
"578759"    "xxxx@gmail.com"    "A Tea" 15.00
"588759"    "xyyy@gmail.com"    "A Tea" 15.00
"598759"    "vtyy@gmail.com"    "A Tea" 15.00
```

**Expected Output**

So if i want to know which all combination categories the customer bought up along with "A Tea",

```
Combinations         Customer count    Combination count   Revenue Split UP
A Tea                 7                   3 ( Or 7)       A Tee = 45 or (425)
A Tea, B Tea          2                   2               A Tea = 350 B Tea = 20
A Tea, B Tea, C Tea   2                   2               A Tea= 30  B Tea=45   C Tea = 445
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me to resolve tis? Any suggestions please?